# how can i fix "ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed"

Tags: android

I have an issue of "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed" when I updated the compileSdkVersion 29 and targetSdkVersion 29. I can not find the answer why it is happening. Search everywhere and the say update the android studio version. but it does not help me.
My android studio version is- 3.5.1

exception is occure in this class-

public class Animation extends AppCompatActivity {

```
String taskId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);
    taskId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("task_id");

    new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            if(AssignedFragment.isOnline()) {
                AssignedFragment.comingAtFirstTime = true;
                Completedfragment.comingAtFirst = true;
            }

            AssignedFragment.changeInLoadSharedPreferencesLogList(Animation.this, "assignArrayList", taskId, "completedArrayList");
            AssignedFragment.changeInLoadSharedPreferencesLogList(Animation.this, "markImpArrayList", taskId, "");
            startActivity(newIntent(Animation.this,navigationDrawer.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
        }
    },3000);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the code that's causing this exception?

Comment: yes I have included the code

Comment: I think it's an animation library problem. when I use the latest version of the library problem get resolved.